# How to get specific set of array inside an object

Tags: php, arrays, json, curl

So what I have here is a JSON response from my PHP cURL, so I'm trying to get the specific group of array under `location` depending where is the  `identifier` value I'm checking.

```
{
"status": "SUCCESS",
"response": {
    "offset": 0,
    "max": 50,
    "count": 2,
    "locations":[
         {
           "identifier":"54320",
           "id": 503892,
           "name":"The Foo"
         },
         {
           "identifier":"54321",
           "id": 503893,
           "name":"The Bar"
         }
    ]
}
```

This is what I've done so far and what I'm trying to do. So I already parse the json above and put it on foreach. Note the identifier is not always an `int` it can also be `string`.

```
$parsed_json = json_decode($phpCurlResponse, true);
$parsed_json = $parsed_json["response"]["locations"];
    foreach($parsed_json as $key => $pj){
        if($pj['identifier'] == "54320"){
            echo $pj['name'].' & '.$pj['id'];//this should display The Foo & 503892
        }
    }
```

I have tried this one and it can only see the first group of `array` under `locations` but when I change the `identifier` value from `54321` to `112233` the response will be `Identifier do not exist.`  can you help me how we achieve this.

Comment: You are sure a location with the identifier `112233` _does_ exist? With the information given so far all is working as expected!?

Comment: I second to @Jeff, are you sure you are getting a subarray with the attribute `112233`?

Comment: @jeff hi mate ! I checked it again and its now working.. I removed the else coz its not necessary i think? ..

Comment: in the received json, there's a syntax error, causing json_decode to fail: `The Bar` has no `"` around it.

Comment: okay done edited ... sorry for the confusion coz i just type the response above to mimic my response :D

Comment: It might be because you are using array notation, not object. `$parsed_json = $parsed_json["response"]->locations;` instead of `$parsed_json = $parsed_json["response"]["locations"];`

Comment: You have some syntax errors with the json. There shouldn't be a comma after the last object in the locations array, and there should be a closing ``}`` after the locations ``]``. After you fix it you should have the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the premature posting but I want you to know that there's nothing wrong with the code above its just had some typo error on the json response I typed,  anyways thank you for the help guys. :) So that's one possible way to get an specific set of array inside an object depending where's the key value you looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is invalid.

1. There shouldn't be a comma after the last object in the `locations` array.
2. There should be a `}` after the `locations` closing array bracket (`]`).

So is the valid JSON.

```
{
  "status": "SUCCESS",
  "response": {
    "offset": 0,
    "max": 50,
    "count": 2,
    "locations": [
      {
        "identifier":"54320",
        "id": 503892,
        "name":"The Foo"
      },
      {
        "identifier":"54321",
        "id": 503893,
        "name":"The Bar"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```